My SpeedBoost doesnt deactivate and my Player stays with the SpeedBoost
I wanted to create a SpeedBoost once I enter a Collectable but unfortunately it is not working.
Once I hit the collectable I get my runSpeed. But my runSpeed stays and doesn't go back to moveSpeed.
For more Information: I can access my moveSpeed and my runSpeed through the Unity Inspector and add a number that will be the move/run Speed of the Player. Before I made the SpeedBoost I added runSpeed on Shift so I can see that it works. I mainly Followed Tutorial on Udemy and tried to add assets etc. of my own.
This is the first question that I am asking so sorry if I didn't explain something. I am new to Unity and just follow many tutorials. This is my whole Player Controller Script. The SpeedBoost code starts at line 68 basically ends on line 90. But the boostTimer and "boosting" added on start.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float runSpeed;
    private float activeSpeed;

    public bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheckPoint;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    public Animator ani;
    private float boostTimer;
    private bool boosting;



   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        boostTimer = 0;
        boosting = false ;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround); 

       activeSpeed = moveSpeed;
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            activeSpeed = runSpeed;
        }
        
        rb.velocity = new Vector2 ( Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * activeSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            if(isGrounded == true)
            {
               rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
            }
            
        } 

        if(rb.velocity.x > 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        }
        if (rb.velocity.x < 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);
        }

        //animation dings
        ani.SetFloat("speed", Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x));
        ani.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
        ani.SetFloat("ySpeed", rb.velocity.y);

        if (boosting)
        {
            boostTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if(boostTimer >= 3)
            {
                runSpeed = moveSpeed;
                boostTimer = 0;
                boosting = false;
            }
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "SpeedBoost")
        {
            boosting = true;
            moveSpeed = runSpeed;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
            
    }

    public void KnockBack()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, jumpForce * .5f);
        ani.SetTrigger("isHit");

    }
}


Assuming that:
activeSpeed is the player's current movement speed;
moveSpeed is the player's walking movement speed (constant);
runSpeed is the player's running movement speed (also constant);
I would assume that in OnTrigger2DSpeed, activeSpeed must be equal to runSpeed, and not moveSpeed - else you just told your code that walking speed is equal to running speed - and then in the next frame you set activeSpeed to moveSpeed that now is equal to running speed.
